# Dimension of a $G$-variety $X$ that is a finite union of $G$-orbits

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions

Suppose that $G$ is an algebraic group acting on a variety $X$, and $X$ is a finite disjoint union of $G$-orbits $\mathcal{O}_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, under this action.  Is it true that the dimension of $X$ is the maximum of the dimensions of the $\mathcal{O}_i$?  It seems like this should be true, and is probably a result of something more general.  Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I only know the following for a fact if we are over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

Let $X=X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_r$ is the decomposition of $X$ into irreducible components and assume without loss of generality that $X_1$ is of maximal dimension.

It is a well-known and basic fact that any $G$-orbit is open in its closure of $G.x$ is the union of $G.x$ and orbits of *strictly* smaller dimension. See [these very nice notes by Michel Brion](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes_luminy.pdf). Now by assumption, there are finitely many $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$ such that $X=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n \overline{G.x_i}$ (disjoint union). Thus, $X_1 = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^n (\overline{G.x_i}\cap X_1)$. Since $X_1$ is irreducible, we have (again wlog) $X_1 =  \overline{G.x_1}\cap X_1$. Thus, 
$$\dim(X)=\dim(X_1)=\dim(\overline{G.x_1}\cap X_1)\le \dim(\overline{G.x_1})=\dim(G.x_1)\le \dim(X).$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes since the relation between the orbits and the variety is finite to one maximum dimension of the orbits is the same with the dimension of X.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, although I still don't understand.  Can you expand on this a bit more?

Comment: Divide the variety X by the action (go to the quotient variety where you send each orbit to a different point). Since the number of orbits is finite, the quotient variety is finite so it has dimension 0. Now we know that the fibers (orbits) have dimension greater than or equal to dim(X)-dim(X/G) = dim(X). Moreover since all orbits are subsets of X their dimensions are less than or equal to the dimension of X. This completes the proof.

Comment: Why do all fibers have dimension greater than or equal to $\dim(X)-\dim(X/G)$?  If this were true, by your reasoning, wouldn't all orbits have the same dimension?  Is this also true, in the case of finitely many orbits?